# How to disable building a project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there some way to keep a project open in eclipse without building it?

I have a few projects in eclipse that don't build because of errors. I just want to use them as reference while I edit and build my main project, however I can't run my main because eclipse complains about all the errors from the other projects (my project does not depend on them)

Answer (score 32):

It's possible to disable building all project automatically, but this is often overkill.

Rather than disable all projects from building automatically, you can right click the problem project in the explorer and select the properties of the project. Then select the builders option, and deselect all the builders. This disables building of that particular project.

In order to clear all the build problems that were previously logged by auto-building, you can got to "problems" or "Markers" tab, and select all and delete the items listed there, they will be recreated (except for your disabled project on the next rebuild)

Comment: This is the best answer because it allows you to continue to use Ctrl-B ("Build all") to build just the project(s) you want. Cheers!

Comment: We often need to setup the project in eclipse for remote debugging and mostly we don't have all the dependencies

Answer (score 7):

Uncheck 'Build automatically' in the projects menu.

You could also filter the displayed errors/warnings for selected working-sets.

BTW: If your 'main' project is compiled (check bin or classes folder) you should be able to run it, regardless of other projects problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to unbind the Ctrl-B key.

- Go to *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys*
- Mark *Build all* in the command list
- press button  <kbd>Unbind Command</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> Right-click and close a project you don't wish to build.

Since I normally work with tens of projects in Eclipse, I have grown to prefer closing project so that Eclipse knows to ignore them. Double clicking a project in the Project Explorer view will reopen it!

More details: https://dzone.com/articles/quick-way-open-closed-project